# Getting Javascript from PDF using iText

Tags: javascript, pdf, itext, adobe, acrobat

I'm using iText to try to get Javascript from fields on a PDF. I've noticed that using `GetAdditionalAction()` will get me the Javascript I need, unless the code is of a certain length. If I put JS on a field for let's say `onMouseEnter` that is more than around ~5 lines long, `GetAdditionalAction()` will truncate this code into an alphanumeric string. In my example, I'm trying to get a bit of code inside an if statement, but since it's too long it returns something like: `630 0 R`. I cannot find any info about this online or anyone else talking about it. Help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You mention `GetAdditionalAction`. The iText 7 methods with that name return `PdfDictionary` instances, not strings. I assume you incorrectly retrieve the JS code from that dictionary.

Comment: @mkl Yes, it doesn't return a string but I'm able to extract the JS from that object because I cannot seem to figure out the proper way to get the JS from that object. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I put JS on a field for let's say `onMouseEnter` that is more than around ~5 lines long, `GetAdditionalAction()` will truncate this code into an alphanumeric string.

Actually `GetAdditionalAction()` does not truncate. What you observe, is that there is a choice for PDF generators when generating **JavaScript** actions:

> **JS** –
>   text string or
>   text stream –
>   *(Required)* A text string or text stream containing the JavaScript script to be executed.
>   **PDFDocEncoding** or Unicode encoding (the latter identified by the Unicode prefix *U+FEFF*) shall be used to encode the contents of the string or stream.

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 217 – Additional entries specific to a JavaScript action)*

Apparently your PDF generator uses a *text string* if the script is up to *~5 lines long* and a *text stream* otherwise. Thus, when you retrieve the value of the **JS** entry from the action dictionary `action`, do something like

```cs
PdfObject direct = action.Get(PdfName.JS, true);
if (direct == null)
{
    [handle case of missing JavaScript script in action]
}
else if (direct.GetObjectType() == PdfObject.STRING)
{
    PdfString scriptString = (PdfString) direct;
    [handle case of JavaScript script contained in text string]
}
else if (direct.GetObjectType() == PdfObject.STREAM)
{
    PdfStream scriptStream = (PdfStream) direct;
    [handle case of JavaScript script contained in text stream]
}
else
{
    [handle case of invalid JavaScript script object type]
}
```

Comment: I didn't mention this explicitly but the example code refers to iText 7.x.

Comment: you are a LIFE SAVER, this worked perfectly. I had to alter some stuff but I got it working. Thank you!

Comment: side question @mkl, do you know how to get javascript from a page action in iText 7 such as PdfName.O? I noticed PdfPage has a SetAdditionalAction but no GetAdditionalAction, any tips?